# How to access node stdlib from typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, std

Node has a lib called `repl`, which I'm trying to use.

`normal.js`:

```
repl = require("repl")
console.log("Poor unfortunate soul");
repl.start("_____>");
```

However I can't seem to tell typescript to do the same thing

```
import * as repl from "repl";
```

Doesn't seem to work. And I've googled all over, and can't seem to find any answer to using what I guess is the node stdlib from typescript.

Comment: what happens if you try `import repl from 'repl';`?

Comment: Stupid question from me: have you installed the `node_modules`?

Comment: Which node modules?

Comment: I've not done much with npm before, I'm new to the ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out I was missing the following:

Typescript has type declaration files to handle the behaviour of untyped js files.

the module I needed to include was  "@types/node"

and the command was

`npm install --save-dev @types/node`

Hope this helps somebody, this was a headache.